# Server side notifications to frontend for PHP

Tags: php, notifications, frontend, backend

I don't know how it's called exactly, but I need that server send notices to frontend, that allow do not refresh page. Such as at the stackoverflow, that show serverside changes like new messages without page refresh. I can solve my problem with always monitoring the server side backend every 5 seconds for example, but it's a very load the server. Help me to solve this problem for PHP, maybe exists some third-party libs for this and tell me how they are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid polling the server for updates, what you're looking for is [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Do you know it's suitable for PHP? And can I use it at shared hosting?

Comment: There are PHP-based WebSockets servers available (socketo.me is one). If you can run the PHP scripts from a CLI, then it would work on shared hosting.

Answer (score 2):

You can either go for [Web Sockets](http://www.websocket.org/) or if you can use HTML5, use [Server Side Events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) to get informed about certain events by remote party.